# Como trabalhar elementos de uma pagina web em python

Tags: javascript, python

Estudo python a algum tempo e criei uma aplicação, agora gostaria apenas de criar uma pagina onde os dados que são armazenados em uma variável fossem exibidos naquele elemento html, mais ou menos como o DOM no JS, só que toda explicação que procuro é terrivelmente confusa pra mim, cheguei a pesquisar sobre django mas nunca acho uma aula simples sobre isso, alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Você pode usar Python com Django ou Flask. Você pode utilizar uma estratégia de ter as páginas html montadas no servidor. Ou seja você vai enviar um form com a requisição o servidor vai processar e lhe retornar outra página. Outra alternativa seria escrever o frontend (parte web) com algum framework js como Angular e usar python pra escrever o backend(servidor) em Django por exemplo.
Isso pode ajudar: https://django-portuguese.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/intro/tutorial01.html
http://www.devfuria.com.br/python/flask/

Comment: Certo, estudar sobre, usar o python como back é justamente o que eu quero, obrigado !

Comment: Só uma coisa, eu não consigo fazer uma aplicação que receba coisas do back-end em python sem ter que recarregar a pagina ? Porque eu quero que só alguns componentes dêem refresh não todos

Comment: Consegue sim. Você serve uma aplicação web e recarrega as partes que quer usando ajax. Dá uma olhada nesse link: https://www.techiediaries.com/python-django-ajax/

Comment: muito obrigado !